# Why am I getting a 500 error from api and api explorer

Tags: php, google-apis-explorer, adsense-api

I am trying to call `listAccountSites` in php via the Adsense Management API and I am continually getting a 500 error. I have tried setting the `pageSize` to different values and still get the error:

> { "error": { "code": 500, "message": "Internal error encountered.", "errors": [ { "message": "Internal error encountered.", "domain": "global", "reason": "backendError" } ], "status": "INTERNAL" } }

I also try to run the request via the live API Explorer and get the 500 error as well. Can someone please look into the issue and let me know how I can resolve it. I have tried with and without the pageSize value and get the same result. I do randomly get a 200 result but it is very sporadic and infrequent, I would expect to get a 200 more often then a 500 which is not the case. I have provided a screenshot of the api explorer giving the error with and without the pagesize set.

Comment: This is an error on Google servers while using their ready-made software. It's not a programming problem that we can help you with

Answer (score -1):

I'm from the Google team that works on the AdSense Management API. On my end, I can see that it appears that the authentication step is timing out for you. I need to reach out to the engineers that work on that piece of the system. I'll edit my answer here when I hear back from them.

Edit: The engineering team got back to me that they were aware of an error with authentication, and it was fixed this morning around 7am PST. Let me know if you are still experiencing any unexpected behavior.

Comment: It's good you could resolve the customer's problem, but this post has no long-term value as a Stackoverflow answer. Would have been better as a comment, and then the question closed as not reproducible.

Comment: I am now seeing timeout errors from the api. I do not get the internal error any longer which is resolved but now it is an Operation timeout. Is this something I can configure in the api call?